# Writing Conditions in Left join sql

Tags: sql-server

I want to know why these queries give different results

```
    Select *  FROM Table1 T1 
    Left Join MyTable MT 
    ON MT.studentId = T1.StudentId 
    AND T1.class = 7



    Select *  FROM Table1 T1 
    Left Join MyTable MT 
    ON MT.studentId = T1.StudentId 
    WHERE T1.class = 7
```

Comment: [Does this help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins/27458534#27458534)

Comment: Thanks but I already know the basics. This has something to do with some rare scenarios of left join.

Comment: This isn't a "rare scenario". It is a straight forward application of the rules described there.

Comment: A `where` clause on the "right" table effectively turns the outer join into an inner join.

Answer (score 2):

The where clause is evaluated after the join. `A left join B` means all tuples  from A together with the matching tuples from B, if no tuples from B match null is the result. Given:

```
create table t1 (studentid int not null, class int not null);
create table t2 (studentid int not null);
insert into t1 values (1,1),(2,2);
insert into t2 values (1);

select * from t1 left join t2 on t1.studentid = t2.studentid;

STUDENTID   CLASS       STUDENTID  
----------- ----------- -----------
      1           1           1
      2           2           -
```

i.e. there is no row in t2 that matches studentid 1 so a null is the result. For:

```
select * from t1 
left join t2 
    on t1.studentid = t2.studentid 
   and t1.class = 1;
```

Nothing changes. For:

```
select * from t1 
left join t2 
    on t1.studentid = t2.studentid 
where t1.class = 1;
```

on the other hand, the where clause is evaluated after the join so t1.studentid  2 is removed from the result.

Comment: In the First Query, it was mentioned `and t1.class = 1;` so why it was not considered in Left Join,

Comment: If this were an inner join, mentioning these conditions (and t1.class = 1;)  in Join and in Where is same, and former gives better performance

Comment: For your first question, it is, but this predicate applies to the join, not the table t1. All rows from t1 by definition of a left join is qualified. For you second question, the DBMS (in your case sql server) is free to evaluate the predicates in whatever order it finds best. I.e. there is no point in guessing if one would outperform the other.

Comment: I can understand, that when we do left join, all entries are eligible... but consider this example. Table t1 has 1000 records, ( 100 for each class 1 to 10 ) and where condition query performs like, left join t1 and t2, then from resulting (1000) select those 100 where class = 7. If my 1st query would have worked as expected, then it would have left joined only 100 from t1 ( not entire 1000) with t2, resulting in 100 records right after Left Join. So tell me why would I want to left join entire 1000 records from t1 when I only want 100 records from t1 as output. There should be a way to do it

Comment: Well thanks, I found What I was looking for, for joining with only 100 records ( class 7 ) and getting only those 100 records ( only class 7 ) I have to use and t1.class = 1 in both Join and Where conditions. :D

Answer (score -2):

Lets say T1 contains 1000 records ( 100 for each class 1 to 10 )

```
Select *  FROM Table1 T1 
Left Join MyTable MT 
ON MT.studentId = T1.StudentId 
AND T1.class = 7
```

This Query : performs left join on only class 7 records of t1 and MT table and prints the entire T1 table

so if I have a class 8 student Id in MT table, it wont be reflected in the Left Join but I will get entire 1000 records from t1

```
Select *  FROM Table1 T1 
Left Join MyTable MT 
ON MT.studentId = T1.StudentId 
WHERE T1.class = 7
```

This Query : performs left join of entire table t1 with MT and in the end due to Where Condition it will display only 100 records from class 7, but

so if I have a class 8 student Id in MT table, it would have been reflected in Left Join but not displayed due to Where Condition

Lastly the optimized query which I was looking for

```
Select *  FROM Table1 T1 
Left Join MyTable MT 
ON MT.studentId = T1.StudentId
AND T1.Class = 7
WHERE T1.class = 7
```

This query combines the impact of the above queries together. 
It left Joins 100 records ( class 7 ) of t1 with MT table ( due to join condition )
and It only Displays only 100 records ( class 7 ) of resultant join due to Where condition.

Comment: Your "optimized" query should just be an inner join. Repeating the filter to turn a left join into an implicit inner join makes little sense to me at all.

Comment: In Inner Join, I will only get those records which are in MT table, I want the entire class 7 records ( weather they are in MT table or not ). So inner join wont work.

Comment: It's not optimized. Your 3rd query is 100% equivalent to the 2nd one. SQL-Server's optimizer is pretty clever to know that.

Comment: Well till join operation 2nd and 3rd are same ( considering optimization level ) , but they dont fetch the same results, 3rd query prunes the un-necessary part ( classes other than 7 ) from my final result set, on the other hand 2nd query will give me entire Table T1 records